# Reading Yes/No Option inside the loop, Does not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
while read line
do

read -p "Are you alright? (y/n) " RESP
if [ "$RESP" = "y" ]; then
  echo "Here i want to do something, but prompt does not wait for the answer"
else
  echo "You need more bash programming"
fi

done < find-spam-send-php-ver2.log
```

==> This script does not work. It does not "wait" for the yes or not option. 
Please I want this script to work. Please let me know, how do modify this.
I have seen this kind of similar things in many linux installation scripts.

Comment: Have you noticed that you have redirected the standard input from a file text? Any `read` to the standard input will get data from the file text!

Comment: use file descriptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this but should work,

```
while read line <&3
do

read -p "Are you alright? (y/n):" RESP

if [ "$RESP" = "y" ]; then
  echo "Here i want to do something, but prompt does not wait for the answer"
else
  echo "You need more bash programming"
fi

done 3< find-spam-send-php-ver2.log
```

Comment: Excuse me, but why does it work? I think `&3` is some sort of custom redirector, but I am not very experienced with this matter. And another question: case of nested while loops, could we define `&3`  and `&4` in order to use each one with one of the loops?

Comment: And please another one: is this `&3` the `file descriptor` thing you talked in your comment? Thanks you.

Comment: Yes &3 is file descriptor. Please go through unix file descriptors in shell readings on Google. Explaining here will end up in long chat series. Apologies for inconvenience.